# Git Bash build doesn't work from terminal in VS Code

Tags: windows, bash, gcc, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have a fresh install of Windows 10 - 64bit

- MinGW - To install gcc
- Git 2.15.1.4 (64 bit )
- VSCode 1.20 (64 bit)

The command I am using is:

```
g++ --version
```

It doesn't work from using the terminal inside VSCode.

However running bash window outside of VSCode, it works fine. Anybody know any suggestions on how to fix it?

[GitBash Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AViRl.png)

[GitBash In VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRODM.png)

Thanks, 
Ciaran

Answer (score 0):

Compare the PATH from your bash outside VSCode:

```
echo $PATH
```

And make sure to get the same PATH in your bash within VSCode:

```
export PATH=/the/path/you/see/in/the/previous/step
```

Once this test is working, check in your VSCode bash where your $HOME is, and modify your `~/.bashrc` in order to set that PATH, as advised in [Microsoft/vscode issue 24989](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24989).

---

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1840643/user1840643) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696323/git-bash-build-doesnt-work-from-terminal-in-vs-code/48699225?noredirect=1#comment84414918_48699225):

> after leaving and coming back to it the next day. It is now working.... Must of needed a restart or something?

This is expected: if the PATH was modified first, the *existing* process did not inherit immediately that change. Closing/re-oppening everything would work however.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But after leaving and coming back to it the next day. It is now working.... Must of needed a restart or something?